# Magento 2 Js file not updating

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.4, static-content, static-content-deploy

I have edited the Js file in my module and tried deleting the file in an appropriate location like pub/static/My_Theme/My_Modul/js/test.js
But still getting the same file when I checked in the source tab of my browser.

I tried all these below

```
rm -rf var/cache/* var/generation/* var/page_cache/* var/view_preprocessed/*
rm -rf pub/static/frontend
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

My environment is in developer mode too.

Even though how many times I run deployment I'm getting the same file. I cleared the browser cache, tried the private window, and also another newly installer browser.
In sometimes I'm getting frustrated on this.

Comment: Clear Cpanel cache and if any other caching like cloudfare then clear that too..

Comment: Also try to run setup upgrade command and then deploy once

Answer (score 1):

Check below possibilities.

1. Make sure that extension is enabled.
2. Check that file is overridden in the theme or not if it's overridden in theme then you have to make change on the overridden file in theme.
3. Run below command.

   **php bin/magento s:up**

   **php bin/magento s:d:c**

   **php bin/magento s:s:d**

Thanks.